# Select a Row in DataGrid and get Values from it with the Row Index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid with about 500 items. The user can load more items, so I change the DataGrid.ItemsSource. When this happens, I lose the focus on the selected Row but I got the row index before.

How do I now set the focus on a row with a index?

I'm using WPF and C# with EF6.1

Code samples:

```
<DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" SelectionChanged="MainDataGrid_SelectionChanged"                      SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                //...
    </DataGrid.Columns>    
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: How are you binding data to you datagrid? Can you provide sample code of what you are doing?

Comment: Can't you use **myGrid.CurrentRowIndex = SavedIndex**  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically by assigning 
the index value to the [SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the datagrid:

```
MainDataGrid.SelectedIndex = yourIndex;
```

Furthermore you might want to scroll the datagrid to the item at the index:

```
MainDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(MainDataGrid.Items[yourIndex]);
```

It might be interesting to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826142/how-to-set-selected-item-of-a-datagrid-programmatically-in-wpf-with-mvvm-applica) question as well.

Comment: @J.Doe What exactly didn't work? Given the code you provided it's hard to guess what you're doing. You might need to give some more code before someone can point you at the right direction.

Comment: I copied your code, there where it schould be. I debugged it to check, if it's working well now, but it didnt.