# Move next and previous in DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I've been trying to figure it out how to move **next** and **previous** through records in a `DataGridView`. I'm using the code below but it doesn't make any action when I press eiher next or previous button. (nothing found as answer helped me)

```
    private void btnNext_Click/btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (linie == 0)
        {
            { linie = tabauto.Rows.Count+1/-1; }
        }
        else {linie ++/--;}
        popAutogari();
    }
```

P.S - `popAutogari();` is the method use to bind the `Grid`.

Any help?

Comment: *Moving* - means changing selected item. In wpf we are using binding: bind `ItemsSource` to collection of items and `SelectedItem` to some property first. To move next/previous you simply obtain selected item index in collection and increment/decrement it (with bounds check ofc). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15826142/1997232).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232943/how-to-move-gridview-selected-row-up-down-on-keyup-or-keydown-press