# WPF DataGrid - How to select cell in position [0,0] from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell".
Currently, when the DataGrid is displayed, no cell is initially selected.

I have two scenarios I need to cater to requiring me to know either of:

1. The cell value.
2. All the values of the column of the selected cell.

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,5,0,0"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableViewModel.DataView}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="true"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
          CanUserSortColumns="True"
          CanUserAddRows="false"
          ColumnWidth="auto"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

There are these additional properties available to bind to:
SelectedItem
CurrentCell (however, this is a struct and not an actual reference to the DataGridCell container.)
SelectedIndex

however, I don't know which one to use, nor how to assign it in the ViewModel as none appear to accept [0,0] coordinates.

If I can work out which property to use to identify the selected cell, I can include something so that when the selected cell property is updated, I can determine if I need the cell value or all the column values and update that list accordingly.

I should also add, the data is not loaded when the control is loaded, here's a snippet from the viewmodel showing how I add the data:

```
class DataTableViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    // notify child classes the DataTable has been loaded
    protected event EventHandler<EventArgs> DataTableLoaded;

    public DataView DataView { get { return _dataView; } set { _dataView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    DataView _dataView;

    DataTable _dataTable;

    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get { return _dataTable; }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
            DataView = value.DefaultView;
            if (DataTableLoaded== null)
                return;
            DataTableLoaded.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

            // Can I put something here to set the selected cell?
        }
    }
```

So, my question is mainly: how do I set the active cell position as [0,0] from the ViewModel when the DataGrid is first displayed?

Further Research:
I found a similar question however the answers appear to only deal with rows and not cells:
[How to set selected item of a DataGrid programmatically in WPF with MVVM application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826142/how-to-set-selected-item-of-a-datagrid-programmatically-in-wpf-with-mvvm-applica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution based on value conversion.
All you have to provide to the converter is the selected item (row data item), the column index and the instance of the `DataGrid`. That's why you would have to use a `MultiBinding`.

The `ItemsControl` only operates on the data views and not the original data source. For the `DataGrid` this is a `DataView`. This means the items of the `DataGrid` are of type `DataRowView` when the data source is a `DataTable` (like in your case).

The `DataGrid` knows two selection states: selected + unfocused and selected + focused.
In order to highlight the row's cell, the way it would be highlighted when the user clicks it, you have to explicitly focus the cell (aside from selecting it).

In the following example, a `MultiBinding` is assigned to the `DataGrid.CurrentCell` property. Because the cell is actually selected by adding the cell's descriptor item of type `DataGridCellInfo` to the `DataGrid.SelectedCells` property, the converter does not have to return an actual value for the `DataGrid.CurrentCell` property as this property is set internally (although setting it explicitly won't do any harm).
The example also introduces a small data structure `SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem>` to carry the selection meta info for the converter. This type is optional and can be replaced with any other type, e.g. a `ValueTuple`.

**DataTableViewModel.cs**
Note that the `DataGrid` will implicitly bind to the `DataTable.DefaultView` property. This means that the `DataTableViewModel.DataView` property from your original implementation is redundant and was therefore removed. Simply bind the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` directly to the `DataTableViewModel.DataTable` property.

```cs
class DataTableViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  // notify child classes the DataTable has been loaded
  // If the event data type is 'EventArgs' (no event data)
  // don't use the generic delegate. Instead use 'EventHandler'.
  protected event EventHandler DataTableLoaded;

  DataTable _dataTable;
  public DataTable DataTable
  {
    get => _dataTable; 
    set
    {
      _dataTable = value;

      // This null check aborts the property setter!
      // Don't return. Instead wrap the event invocation into the body of the if...
      //if (DataTableLoaded == null) ==> Bad
        //return; ==> Bad
      // ...or even better use the '?' operator to compact your code.
      // Instead of 'new EventArgs()` you should use 'EventArgs.Empty'!
      // Consider moving event invocation to a dedicated invocator method 'OnDataTableLoaded'.
      this.DataTableLoaded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

      NotifyPropertyChanged();

      // Can I put something here to set the selected cell?
      // Yes:      
      SelectDataCell(rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0);
    }
  }

  private SelectedTableCellInfo<DataRowView> selectedCellInfo = SelectedTableCellInfo.Empty;
  public SelectedTableCellInfo<DataRowView> SelectedCellInfo
  {
    get => this.selectedCellInfo;
    set 
    { 
      this.selectedCellInfo = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private void SelectDataCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
  {
    DataRowView selectedRowView = this.DataTable.DefaultView[rowIndex];

    // Trigger the converter
    this.SelectedCellInfo = new(selectedRowView, columnIndex);
  }
}
```

**SelectedTableCellInfo.cs**

```cs
public readonly struct SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> : IEquatable<SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem>>
{
  // Default constructor in struct requires .NET 6.0 or greater
  public SelectedTableCellInfo()
  {
    this.RowItem = default;
    this.ColumnIndex = -1;
  }

  public SelectedTableCellInfo(object? rowItem, int columnIndex)
  {
    this.RowItem = rowItem;
    this.ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
  }

  public static SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> Empty => new(default, -1);

  public override string ToString() => $"({this.RowItem ?? "NULL"};{this.ColumnIndex})";
  public bool Equals(SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> other) => other.RowItem == this.RowItem && other.ColumnIndex == this.ColumnIndex;
  public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(this.RowItem, this.ColumnIndex);
  public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> info && Equals(info);

  public object? RowItem { get; }
  public int ColumnIndex { get; }

  public static bool operator ==(SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> left, SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> right) => left.Equals(right);
  public static bool operator !=(SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> left, SelectedTableCellInfo<TRowItem> right) => !(left == right);
}
```

**SelectedDataCellInfoConverter.cs**

```cs
public class SelectedDataCellInfoConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    DataGrid dataGrid = values
      .OfType<DataGrid>()
      .First();
    SelectedTableCellInfo<DataRowView> selectedCellInfo = values
      .OfType<SelectedTableCellInfo<DataRowView>>()
      .First();

    if (!dataGrid.HasItems
      || selectedCellInfo == SelectedTableCellInfo<DataRowView>.Empty)
    {
      return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    // In case UI virtualization is enabled and the target row is not generated
    // we have to bring the item into view to force container generation
    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(selectedCellInfo.RowItem);

    var dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(selectedCellInfo.RowItem, dataGrid.Columns[selectedCellInfo.ColumnIndex]);

    // Select the cell
    dataGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
    dataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);

    /* Focus the cell's container */
    FrameworkElement cellContentHost = dataGridCellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(selectedCellInfo.RowItem);
    var dataGridCell = cellContentHost?.Parent as DataGridCell;
    _ = dataGridCell?.Focus();

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <DataTableViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"
            SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.CurrentCell>
      <MultiBinding>
        <MultiBinding.Converter>
          <local:SelectedDataCellInfoConverter />
        </MultiBinding.Converter>

        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        <Binding Path="SelectedCellInfo" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </DataGrid.CurrentCell>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a difficult task, especially considering the implementation in the MVVM pattern. You will have to provide some kind of two-way communication between the View and the ViewModel to select a cell.

One way to do this is:

```cs
using Simplified; // Space with my implementations of ViewModelBase and RelayCommand.
using System.Data;

namespace Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006
{
    public class CellInfoData : ViewModelBase
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get => Get<bool>(); set => Set(value); }
        public int Row { get; }
        public int Column { get; }

        public CellInfoData(int row, int column)
        {
            Row = row;
            Column = column;
        }
    }
    public class CellContentInfoData<T> : CellInfoData
    {
        public T Content { get => Get<T>(); set => Set(value); }
        public CellContentInfoData(int row, int column) : base(row, column) { }
    }

    public class CellIntInfoData : CellContentInfoData<int>
    {
        public CellIntInfoData(int row, int column) : base(row, column) { }
    }
    public class CellStringInfoData : CellContentInfoData<string>
    {
        public CellStringInfoData(int row, int column) : base(row, column) { }
    }

    public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public DataTable Table { get => Get<DataTable>(); private set => Set(value); }

        public CellInfoData? LastSelectedCell { get => Get<CellInfoData>(); private set => Set(value); }

        public SomeViewModel()
        {
            DataTable table = new ();
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(CellIntInfoData)));
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(CellStringInfoData)));


            foreach (var item in new (int, string)[] { (1, "First"), (2, "Second"), (3, "Third" ) })
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                CellInfoData cell = new CellIntInfoData(table.Rows.Count, 0) { Content = item.Item1 };
                cell.PropertyChanged += CellPropertyChanged;
                row[0] = cell;
                cell = new CellStringInfoData(table.Rows.Count, 1) { Content = item.Item2 };
                cell.PropertyChanged += CellPropertyChanged;
                row[1] = cell;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            Table = table;
        }

        private void CellPropertyChanged(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is CellInfoData cell && e.PropertyName == nameof(CellInfoData.IsSelected))
            {
                if (cell.IsSelected)
                {
                    LastSelectedCell = cell;
                }
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand SelectedCell00 => GetCommand(() =>
        {
            ((CellInfoData)Table.Rows[0][0]).IsSelected = true;
        });
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006
{
    public partial class SelectedCellWindow : Window
    {
        public SelectedCellWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

    public static class DataGridCellHelper
    {
        const string stringTemplate =
@"
<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
              xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006;assembly=Core2023"">
    <ContentControl Content=""{{Binding {0}}}""
                    local:DependencyObjectHelper.First=""{{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}}}""
                    local:DependencyObjectHelper.Second=""{{Binding Content.IsSelected, RelativeSource={{RelativeSource Self}}}}""/>
</DataTemplate>
";
        //local:DependencyObjectHelper.Second=""{{Binding Content.IsSelected, RelativeSource={{RelativeSource Self}}}}""
        public static readonly EventHandler<DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs> OnGeneratingColumn = (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(string.Format(stringTemplate, e.PropertyName))
            };
        };
    }

    public static class DependencyObjectHelper
    {
        public static object GetFirst(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return obj.GetValue(FirstProperty);
        }

        public static void SetFirst(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(FirstProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for First.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "First",
                typeof(bool?),
                typeof(DependencyObjectHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
                {
                    PropertyChangedCallback = (d,e) => d.SetValue(SecondProperty, e.NewValue),
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
                });
        public static object GetSecond(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return obj.GetValue(SecondProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSecond(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SecondProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Second.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Second",
                typeof(bool?),
                typeof(DependencyObjectHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool?) null)
                {
                    PropertyChangedCallback = (d, e) => d.SetValue(FirstProperty, e.NewValue),
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
                });

    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006.SelectedCellWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters;assembly=CommonCore"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SelectedCellWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SomeViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <!--<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Jase99.Question77673006"
                      x:Key="contentControl">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding }"
                            local:DependencyObjectHelper.First="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"
                            local:DependencyObjectHelper.Second="{Binding Content.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CellIntInfoData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, StringFormat='Number: 0'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CellStringInfoData}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Text:"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Content}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="{x:Static local:DataGridCellHelper.OnGeneratingColumn}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell">
        </DataGrid>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding LastSelectedCell.Row, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{Binding LastSelectedCell.Column, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <Button Content="Selected Cell 0,0"
                    Command="{Binding SelectedCell00}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

If the task is more local: select a cellqre in the DataGrid by index. Then it can be solved more simply. Here is an example of a clicker selecting cell (0, 0).

```cs
        private void SelectedCell00Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            => GetCell(dataGrid, 0, 0).IsSelected = true;
        private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);
            DataGridColumn column = dataGrid.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(columnIndex);
            FrameworkElement cellContent = column.GetCellContent(row);
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(cellContent);
            return cell;
        }
```

You can connect such a method to an event from the ViewModel, or pass it as a delegate to the ViewModel and call it from there as needed.